# Printing lines two lines above pattern

Tags: text-processing

How can I print the contents of a file minus everything including and
below the line above the first occurrence of a pattern?

Say the pattern is "^Previous" on line 15; then I would like to print
lines 1--13.

Comment: there is no mention of excluding the line above the match in the other question

Comment: Please provide an example

Comment: @roaima, an example of what?  I have already given an example.

Comment: You haven't given an example. You've told us what you want. Please include a short example of a file that contains your desired exclusion pattern, and then show the desired result.

Comment: @roaima, the 2nd paragraph is an example.  if you want a different kind of example, you should give a reason.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about KISS

```
sed '1,/^Previous/!d' file | head -n -2
```

Answer (score 5):

`sed` can do this all by itself:

```
sed -n '$!N;/.*PATTERN.*/q;P;D' infile
```

It's very simple: turn on silent mode, use a sliding window (via `N` and `D`, so that there are always two lines in the pattern space), `q`uit if encountering `PATTERN` otherwise `P`rint the first line in the pattern space and restart the cycle.

With `gnu sed` it's even shorter as it can `Q`uit without auto-printing so you can skip silent mode:

```
sed  '$!N;/.*PATTERN.*/Q;P;D' infile
```